# How do temporarily disassociate an AWS SQS queue from triggering Lambda for transitory buildup of messages onto queue?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have an AWS lambda that is triggered upon a message being added to an SQS queue. A DLQ also exists for any failed messages. For sake of example, the names are
LambdaName1,QueueName1, QueueName1DLQ

The Lambda (LambdaName1) calls a downstream api service. I'm interested in temporarily suspending the lambda in order to allow messages to build on the SQS queue (QueueName1).
At some later point in time, I would like to "reconnect" the queue to the lambda and allow processing to continue. At that point in time, the batch of messages on the queueName1 should all be processed.

How can I achieve the above using c# alone? Can I achieve this using c# alone?

If only I could use the AWS .NET SDK to perform the same actions that is performed in the aws lambda console below..
[image]

Here the concept of "Enabled" and "Disabled" emerges. Is this something controllable via cli, or sdk?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can [postpone message visibility](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-delay-queues.html) for up to 15 minutes at a time. That's a good solution for some situations.

Comment: Thats an interesting idea. The big downside to that is that it requires advance knowledge of time , 15 min. I dont have advance knowledge of this prior to needing to disassociate the queue

Comment: You can disable event source mapping temporarily [update-event-source-mapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/update-event-source-mapping.html#update-event-source-mapping) and enable it back whenever you want.

Comment: Perhaps you could schedule a Lambda to run every N minutes (N=15 or some fraction), test for the condition to pause/resume SQS, and make the relevant API call to do that. Or have the scheduled Lambda simply do the resume function, while other code (presumably already in place) detects the pause condition.

Comment: @samtoddler, if you could post a sample code using update-event-source-mapping using c# as originally posted, I would gladly accept as answer!

Comment: @jbooker No experience with C# though [UpdateEventSourceMappingRequest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/index.html?page=Lambda/MLambdaUpdateEventSourceMappingUpdateEventSourceMappingRequest.html)

Comment: I have a feeling its either setting max concurrency to 0, or temp disassociating event source mapping but cant find either of these accomplished using c#

Comment: also wondering about adding delay to messages, then removing message delay in batch at later time